# Microsoft Team Foundation Solution Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, github, tfs

So i have a project on the Microsoft version of GitHub, and I'm trying to figure out how to mark a project as "released" under the build category. How do I move my first 'Iteration' to be released?

Also how to a provide a shareable link for people to download said project?

Answer (score 0):

The released tab is only for use with the continuously release to azure template.

To release publicly you would use a post-test powershell to push the bits where you need them. I use an azure blob store.